# (CVS) Detect when files associated with tag/label have changed

Tags: tags, cvs, label

How can I detect when a developer updates files associated with a tag/label in CVS, then changes the tag to point to the new versions?  The use case is developers surreptitiously making changes after the checked-in and tagged files have been peer-reviewed and approved, but before they have been built & deployed.  I would like to avoid getting & diffing all the files at two distinct points in time.  Is it possible to get a checksum of all files associated with a tag?

Yes, I know there are "challenges" with the process.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CVS `taginfo` hook to either log or email whenever a developer tags anything. There is example usage in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406697/cvs-how-to-get-the-date-when-a-tag-is-created). This would give you some visibility on who is retagging things and when.

CVS does not provide checksumming of files but you could certainly add in a checksumming taginfo hook and the output could be appended to your log/email. The only thing to be wary of here is [CVS keyword substitution](http://ximbiot.com/cvs/manual/cvs-1.12.13/cvs_12.html). If you make use of that at all then any simple checksumming will be pointless.

Setting aside the technicalities, this may just be a policy issue. If you don't want your developers retagging things (except under exceptional circumstances) then make that the policy and make them aware of it. Make sure there is a known process for dealing with code changes that need to be made after the review stage.